# Jasmine doesn't see my JS file? ReferenceError: marsRover is not defined

Tags: javascript, jasmine

MarsRover.js

```
var marsRover = function() {
    return 0;
};
```

MarsRoverSpec.js (this doesn't work)

```
describe("MarsRover Kata Tests", function() {
    it("has function named marsRover", function() {
        expect(marsRover()).toBe(0);
    });
});
```

The above code does not work:  ReferenceError: marsRover is not defined

MarsRoverSpec.js(this works)

```
var marsRover = function() {
    return 0;
};

describe("MarsRover Kata Tests", function() {
    it("has function named marsRover", function() {
        expect(marsRover()).toBe(0);
    });
});
```

I'm guessing I need to include or require the JS file.  What's the best or easiest way to do this?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Jasmine Spec Runner v2.0.0</title>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine_favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/boot.js"></script>

  <!-- include source files here... -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../Mars Rover/src/MarsRover.js"></script>

  <!-- include spec files here... -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../Mars Rover/spec/MarsRoverSpec.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you wrapped you code in MarsRover.js in javascript's onload?

Comment: @AbhishekPrakash Just tried it onload.  That seems to stop jasmine from running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a duplicate MarsRover.js file in the root directory of the app.  Not sure why this was an issue since I clearly specify in the html the js file is in the src folder.